# Use xsl:number together with xsl:for-each-group

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Consider the following XML document:

```
<cities>
    <city name="Milano"  country="Italia"      pop="5"/>
    <city name="Paris"   country="France"      pop="7"/>
    <city name="München" country="Deutschland" pop="4"/>
    <city name="Lyon"    country="France"      pop="2"/>
    <city name="Venezia" country="Italia"      pop="1"/>
 </cities>
```

Using the above XML document and XSLT, I want to get the following output (desired output):

```
1.Country: Italia:
       1.1. City: Milano   
       Population: 5 Millions
       1.2. City: Venezia   
        Population: 1 Millions
       total Population: 6 Millions

    2.Country: France:
       2.1. City: Paris   
       Population: 7 Millions
       2.2 City: Lyon   
       Population: 2 Millions
       total Population: 9 Millions

    3.Country: Deutschland:
       3.1 City: München   
        Population: 4 Millions
        total Population: 4 Millions
```

Here is my attempt (it doesn't give me what i want to get):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="cities">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
            <xsl:number format="1."/>Country: <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>:
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <!--<xsl:number count="current-group()|@name" format="1.1." level="multiple"/>: Error The current-group() function cannot be used in a pattern -->
            City: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />   
            Population: <xsl:value-of select="@pop"/> Millions</xsl:for-each>
            total Population: <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@pop)"/> Millions
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:number` the way you tried mainly helps with numbering based on the input structure but perhaps the following suffices:

```
 <xsl:template match="cities">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
            <xsl:number format="1." value="position()"/>Country: <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>:
            <xsl:variable name="group-pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              
            <xsl:number value="$group-pos, position()" format="1.1." />: City: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />   
            Population: <xsl:value-of select="@pop"/> Millions
             </xsl:for-each>
            total Population: <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@pop)"/> Millions
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

Depending on the result format (like HTML) it might be easier to just construct nested `ol/li` lists and let them be numbered/styled with CSS.

Or create a temporary `country/city` hierarchy first for the xsl:numbering you had:

```
 <xsl:template match="cities">
    <xsl:variable name="countries">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="city" group-by="@country">
        <country name="{current-grouping-key()}" pop="{sum(current-group()/@pop)}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </country>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$countries/country">
        <xsl:number format="1."/>Country: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>:
            <xsl:for-each select="city">
              
            <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1.1." count="country | city"/>: City: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />   
            Population: <xsl:value-of select="@pop"/> Millions
            </xsl:for-each>
        total Population: <xsl:value-of select="@pop"/> Millions
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it works fine.